# customize the output log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I try to customize the output of log4j, for this I use **org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout**.

My current output is :

2016-11-30 10:04:42,928 INFO  [org.mobicents.smsc.library.CdrGenerator] OrangeSmsc,18004,null,null,null,id:0000018004 sub:00,,21

I want it to look like this:

2016-11-30 10:04:42 OrangeSmsc,18004,null,null,null,id:0000018004 sub:00,,21

For this I use this pattern:

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %m%n"/> 
</layout>
```

but it doesn't work.

The full appender description:

```
<appender name="CDR" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/cdr.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Maybe you are applying this pattern for the wrong appender.

Comment: `<appender name="CDR" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender"> 
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/> 
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/cdr.log"/> 
     <param name="Append" value="true"/> 
     <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

     <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %m%n"/> 
     </layout> 
 </appender>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run the log4j log with the pattern you mentioned. There is no issue on that. Only thing is it doesn't work until I **comment** the following line

```
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

This is the final appender looks like. (Please note that I have removed the jboss logger error handler)

```
<appender name="CDR" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler" /> -->
    <param name="File" value="cdr.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <!-- 
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" /> -->
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

This is the log I put on java class.

```
logger.debug("Log4j appender configuration is successful !!");
```

This is the addepter I used and following is the output file content.

```
2016-11-30 Log4j appender configuration is successful !!
```